# Autenticação usando for ou filter ionic 3

Tags: firebase, ionic3

Olá, gostaria de saber se eu posso usar validação sem sem pela configuração do "Authentication" do FIREBASE, tenho uma lista de objetos,

```
if(placa == 'ABC123' && senha == '123')
   alert('logado')
else if(placa != 'ABC123')
   alert('placa errada')
else if (senha != '123')
   alert('senha incorreta')
```

Antes, pego todos os registros no DB, desta forma trago todos os ítens que preciso

```
    getTrucks() {
    this.truckService.getTrucks()
          .subscribe(
            result => this.trucks = result
          )
  }
```

já tentei usar o for e o filter, mas a validação não dá certo
usando o for

```
    filterTruck() {
    return this.trucks.filter((item) => {
      if(item.placa == this.truck.placa && item.password == this.truck.password) {
        console.log(item)
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
          this.auth.authentication(true);
          this.auth.truckLogedd(user);
          return true;
      } else if(item.placa != this.truck.placa) {
        console.log('Placa não confere')        
          return false;
      } else if(item.senha != this.truck.senha) {
        console.log('Senhanão confere')        
          return false;
      }
      return false;
    })  
  }
```

agora, usando o filter para tentar validar

```
    filterTruck(users) {
    for(let user of users) {
      if(user.password != this.truck.password || user.placa != this.truck.placa) {
        this.showAlert('Ops!', 'Senha ou placa errada!')
        break;
      } else {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
        this.auth.authentication(true);
        this.auth.truckLogedd(user);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

estou tentando fazer essa validação sem precisar usar o "Authentication" do firebase, é interessante fazer assim ou usando o "Auhtentication" mesmo ?

Answer (score 0):

Se você está fazendo a Autentificação com o Firebase você pode trabalhar com o FormBuilder e Validators que é nativo do Angular 2+ .

Comment: Perdão Hugo Costa, não me expressei bem, é autenticação e não validação, e é justamente isso, quero fazer uma autenticação sem precisar o método próprio de authentication do Firebase, não sei se consegui explicar....não é sobre validar campos....